# how can we delete the pics sent via whatsapp in nokia lumia 510

Tags: lumia, whatsapp

I am unable to delete the photos, received through whatsapp in nokia lumia 510. How can i delete these pics from Nokia lumia 510? When i delete these photos from gallery, these are not deleted and are visible again.

Answer (score 1):

Go to whatsapp, go into the whatsapp conversation. Click on the contact/group on the top. The group/contact information appears with members/status etc. Swipe right to go to media. You can see all the photos/videos. Delete what you don't need.

If you have already deleted them from gallery, then only the thumbnail of the pic should be visible. You can delete that as well.

But if you still see the pics, there is some bug on your phone.

Comment: Your first option only deletes photos from the WhatsApp conversation, but the photos are still saved onto the device

Comment: @Kelvinelove Files app can be used as mentioned in the other answer. Or default save to phone option can be turned off.

Answer (score 1):

Using the file explorer on Windows Phone 8, navigate to (Phone or SDCard)\Pictures\Whatsapp, then delete everything you dont want, or the whole folder if you don't want anything there.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Microsoft store and download the [Files](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/store/apps/Files/9WZDNCRFJ3PL) app. This is a file manager application. Use that to browse through the files on both your phone, and your Micro SD card. If you already have the application, then open it and navigate to: `SD card\Pictures\Whatsapp`, mark and delete the photos you want to remove from your phone's storage and gallery.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

1. Open WhatsApp
2. Tap on the group
3. Tap the bottom right corner
4. Clear all chat history

Comment: Your first option only deletes photos from the WhatsApp conversation, but the photos are still saved onto the device